# Moved my spring boot application from mullti module to zero module and application.properties is not detected on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My application has a lot of modules, namely

- entity
- dto
- rest-web

After removing all the module and combining the application like the default template in https://start.spring.io/, my application can start but it didn't recognize application.properties even though I have put the properties there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the parent `pom.xml` file does not have `<packaging>pom<packaging>`, otherwise the IDE wont recognize the spring application correctly